# Dotnet core Console Application slack bot logger

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, slack

I have a .netCore logger console application. I would like to add a slackLogger class library to my project and therefore use a slackLog function in the driver to log to slack.

I found this code online:

```
using System;
using SlackBotMessages;

namespace SlackLogger
{ 
    public static class SlackLogger
    {
        var WebHookUrl = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/Your/WebHook/Url";

        var client = new SbmClient(WebHookUrl);

        var message = new Message("New member registered.").SetUserWithEmoji("Website", Emoji.Loudspeaker);
        message.AddAttachment(new Attachment()
        .AddField("Name", "jane doe", true)
        .AddField("Website", "codeshare.co.uk", true)
        .AddField("Job Title", "Developer", true)
        .AddField("Company", "comp", true)
        .AddField("Bio","something about me)
        .SetThumbUrl("https://codeshare.co.uk/media/1508/paul-seal-profile-2019.jpg?width=500&height=500&mode=crop&anchor=top")
        .SetColor("#f96332")
    );

    client.Send(message);
    }
}
```

I added th SlackBotMessages package to the dependencies. However, noone of the identifiers is recognized by the program.

I don 't see what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: A lot of syntax errors!

Answer (score 0):

I corrected the syntax errors, does it work now?

```
using System;
using SlackBotMessages;

namespace SlackLogger
{

    public static class SlackLogger
    {
        static string WebHookUrl = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/Your/WebHook/Url";

        static SbmClient client = new SbmClient(WebHookUrl);

        static Message message = new Message("New member registered.").SetUserWithEmoji("Website", Emoji.Loudspeaker);
        message.AddAttachment(new Attachment()
            .AddField("Name", "jane doe", true)
            .AddField("Website", "codeshare.co.uk", true)
            .AddField("Job Title", "Developer", true)
            .AddField("Company", "comp", true)
            .AddField("Bio","something about me")
            .SetThumbUrl("https://codeshare.co.uk/media/1508/paul-seal-profile-2019.jpg?width=500&height=500&mode=crop&anchor=top")
            .SetColor("#f96332")
            );

        client.Send(message);
    }
}
```